# SOA, RPC and interproject dependancies

Tags: java, soa, rpc, software-design, project-structure

My understanding of SOA: Various systems in a business need to do security checks, so it makes sense to use the same process and therefore have a SecurityCheck service. The service could then be called in a variety of ways - soap, rpc, http request.

If this makes sense so far then my question is with regards to the dependencies between the service and rpc client:

```
public interface SecurityCheckService {
    public SecurityCheckResults check(String name);
}

public class SecurityCheckResults {
    private Date instant;
    private int score;
    //getter & setters
}

public class RpcClient {
    private SecurityCheckService remoteService;

    public boolean check(int personId) {
        String name = "Person" + personId;
        int score = remoteService.check(name).getScore();
        return score > 10;
    }
}
```

Should there be 3 seperate projects, where the `SecurityCheckService` project and the `RpcClient` project depend on `SecurityCheckResults` project?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create 2 projects: one for `SecurityCheckService` and another for `RpcClient`. `SecurityCheckResults` is only class for returning results(the same as int, double or smth else). `SecurityCheckResults` in your code isn't very large class, so you can provide it to clients together with stubs of `SecurityCheckService` service.